# How to load ADInterstitialAd only when required in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, iad, interstitial

I would like to show interstitial ads in my iOS application for some specified time interval.
Also, I do not want to disturb the User Interaction. I would like to show this Interstitial Ad when user tries to navigate from the scree/some other action.

But, I don't see any method/call in iOS that would load the InterstitialAd when required. 
Also, `[interstitialAdObj presentFromViewController]` is also deprecated in iOS 7.

My question is, what is the another way to show/present the interstitial ads only when required?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me in iOS 7. Found in the ADInterstitialAdDelegate

```
-(BOOL)presentInView:(UIView *)containerView;
```

Also

```
-(BOOL)requestInterstitialAdPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

I hope that helps you.